# rvest R scraping - Missing tables from html_table()

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am beginner with rvest. I am trying to scrape some tables from the website of the Italian Home Office. I use codes based on-line tutorials, but html_table fails do find any table.
This happens when I try to get all the tables:

```
url <- "http://finanzalocale.interno.gov.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1030491450/cod/4/anno/2014/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/04"
webpage <- read_html(url)
tables <- html_table(webpage)
table1 <- tables[[1]]
```

and also when I try to get a single one using the Xpath

```
url <- "http://finanzalocale.interno.gov.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1030491450/cod/4/anno/2014/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/04"
table <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="center"]/div[3]/table') %>%
  html_table()
table <- table[[1]]
head(table)
```

The issue seems to be specific to this website, because the above codes work on, for example, wikipedia pages.

Solutions to similar problems posted on this website (e.g. removing comment tags) did not work for me.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the page is generated with javascript.  Compare the results from read_html(url) with the web page's html.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I saved the results from read_html(url) using write_xml. It is indeed a different page. The saved page says "Servizio sospeso. La sua richiesta è stata bloccata dai sistemi posti a protezione del sito web. etc etc" which you can translate as "Service suspended. Your request was blocked by the protection system. etc etc"

After googling, it looks like the same issues discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46153600/html-table-scraping-and-exporting-to-csv-attribute-error
but in this post they propose a solution using Python, not R

Answer (score 2):

Works *just fine* without RSelenium or splashr:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
pg <- read_html("http://finanzalocale.interno.gov.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1030491450/cod/4/anno/2014/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/04")

html_nodes(pg, "table.table-striped") %>%
  purrr::map(html_table) %>%
  purrr::map(as_tibble)
## [[1]]
## # A tibble: 75 x 11
##    `FUNZIONI E SERVIZI / … Personale  `Acquisto di beni … `Prestazioni di…
##    <chr>                   <chr>      <chr>               <chr>           
##  1 Funzioni generali di a… 141.967.7… 2.489.137,83        59.941.306,62   
##  2 Organi istituzionali, … 16.229.61… 320.049,90          8.575.927,57    
##  3 indennità per gli orga… 0,00       0,00                4.741.000,00    
##  4 - Segreteria generale,… 40.013.84… 353.042,85          13.399.011,09   
##  5 Gestione economica, fi… 7.925.580… 48.425,00           8.885.886,94    
##  6 Gestione delle entrate… 7.630.190… 12.111,52           13.313.546,15   
##  7 Gestione dei beni dema… 2.166.540… 1.759,99            1.233.312,68    
##  8 Ufficio tecnico         14.404.02… 67.468,00           2.940.932,06    
##  9 Anagrafe, stato civile… 16.826.86… 293.263,23          6.139.023,55    
## 10 Altri servizi generali… 36.771.12… 1.393.017,34        5.453.666,58    
## # ... with 65 more rows, and 7 more variables: `Utilizzo di beni di
## #   terzi` <chr>, Trasferimenti <chr>, `Interessi passivi e oneri
## #   finanziari diversi` <chr>, `Imposte e tasse` <chr>, `Oneri
## #   straordinari della gestione corrente` <chr>, `Ammortamenti di
## #   esercizio` <chr>, Totale <chr>
## 
## [[2]]
## # A tibble: 75 x 11
##    `FUNZIONI E SERVIZI / … Personale  `Acquisto di beni … `Prestazioni di…
##    <chr>                   <chr>      <chr>               <chr>           
##  1 Funzioni generali di a… 131.219.7… 1.153.701,07        31.627.112,30   
##  2 Organi istituzionali, … 15.658.15… 94.401,50           5.841.240,89    
##  3 indennità per gli orga… 0,00       0,00                3.769.143,70    
##  4 Segreteria generale, p… 38.448.56… 167.482,23          7.507.263,62    
##  5 Gestione economica, fi… 7.662.138… 29.961,40           6.347.472,21    
##  6 Gestione delle entrate… 7.487.402… 7.671,92            2.497.130,97    
##  7 Gestione dei beni dema… 2.100.595… 1.759,99            852.589,53      
##  8 Ufficio tecnico         11.334.26… 47.329,00           1.568.994,43    
##  9 Anagrafe, stato civile… 16.144.91… 223.148,43          4.077.270,69    
## 10 Altri servizi generali… 32.383.70… 581.946,60          2.935.149,96    
## # ... with 65 more rows, and 7 more variables: `Utilizzo di beni di
## #   terzi` <chr>, Trasferimenti <chr>, `Interessi passivi e oneri
## #   finanziari diversi` <chr>, `Imposte e tasse` <chr>, `Oneri
## #   straordinari della gestione corrente` <chr>, `Ammortamenti di
## #   esercizio` <chr>, Totale <chr>
## 
## [[3]]
## # A tibble: 74 x 11
##    `FUNZIONI E SERVIZI / … Personale  `Acquisto di beni … `Prestazioni di…
##    <chr>                   <chr>      <chr>               <chr>           
##  1 Funzioni generali di a… 5.593.882… 2.190.159,89        22.691.402,00   
##  2 Organi istituzionali, … 463.851,43 1.649.220,45        2.549.386,60    
##  3 indennità per gli orga… 0,00       0,00                554.624,70      
##  4 Segreteria generale, p… 1.312.740… 47.613,00           8.238.186,49    
##  5 Gestione economica, fi… 227.143,48 12.365,99           2.101.177,76    
##  6 Gestione delle entrate… 220.687,71 16.698,92           3.981.304,84    
##  7 Gestione dei beni dema… 62.536,51  293,70              255.524,99      
##  8 Ufficio tecnico         1.933.388… 27.547,69           1.236.148,00    
##  9 Anagrafe, stato civile… 394.806,86 69.201,92           1.971.067,96    
## 10 Altri servizi generali  978.727,38 367.218,22          2.358.605,36    
## # ... with 64 more rows, and 7 more variables: `Utilizzo di beni di
## #   terzi` <chr>, Trasferimenti <chr>, `Interessi passivi e oneri
## #   finanziari diversi` <chr>, `Imposte e tasse` <chr>, `Oneri
## #   straordinari della gestione corrente` <chr>, `Ammortamenti di
## #   esercizio` <chr>, Totale <chr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RSelenium` to open a browser in which the page is generated and then scrape the tables with `rvest` (just like you were doing):

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("http://finanzalocale.interno.gov.it/apps/floc.php/certificati/index/codice_ente/1030491450/cod/4/anno/2014/md/0/cod_modello/CCOU/tipo_modello/U/cod_quadro/04")
webpage <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
tables <- webpage %>% html_table(fill=T)
```